# "ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections" Error with pool connections to mysql from node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, connection-pooling

I have about 20 node.js files that use the following configuration to access my db:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: databaseHost,
    user: databaseUser,
    password: databasePassword,
    database: databaseName,
    multipleStatements: true
});
```

The functions all use the following pattern:

```
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
        // Use the connection

        var sql = "...sql statement...";
        var inserts = [...inserts...];

        connection.query(sql, inserts, function (error, results, fields) {

            // And done with the connection.
            connection.release();

            // Handle error after the release.
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {
                callback(null, results);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I recently started getting the error:

```
"ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections"
```

on calls to any of my functions.  I don't really understand the pool concept well enough.  If each function is creating a pool, does that create a separate pool each time that function is called?

I understand get connection and release connection.  Just don't really get the createPool.

I tried to log the following:

```
console.log(pool.config.connectionLimit);     // passed in max size of the pool
console.log(pool._freeConnections.length);    // number of free connections awaiting use
console.log(pool._allConnections.length);     // number of connections currently created, including ones in use
console.log(pool._acquiringConnections.length); // number of connections in the process of being acquired
```

the result was:

```
10
0
0
0
```

I can increase the number of connections but would like to have some better understanding of why the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

If your createPool is called inside functions everytime there has to be a query, then yes, it is grave! Instead, have a different file only for mysql connection. Write a class where you create a pool inside a function, and then in the constructor you could simply return the connection from the pool. That way, if you simply require this file anywhere in your project, and create an object of the class, you could then simply use it to query and release!

Comment: could you provide an example?  Also, if calling that function which creates and returns a connection why would that be any different?  Wouldn't that function will be called multiple times which in turn would cause it to create multiple pools?